# Robust higher statistical moments in IDL

Tags: statistics, idl-programming-language

I'm working with noisy data in IDL, so I've been using STDDEV and [robust_sigma](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/robust/robust_sigma.pro)
. There are papers on robust [skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) and [kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis), for instance [[1]](http://www.cirano.qc.ca/realisations/grandes_conferences/methodes_econometriques/white.pdf) and [[2]](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/publications/papers/RobCum-aistats.pdf), but are there implementations, as for standard deviation?  (in IDL or maybe C?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/robust/robust_sigma.pro states:

```
; OPTIONAL OUPTUT KEYWORD:
;       GOODVEC = Vector of non-trimmed indices of the input vector
```

So one calls robust_sigma with an extra parameter that keeps track of the "good indices" in the data, those used to compute the robust_sigma, as opposed to those ignored in its computation.

```
  good_indices = lonarr(width)
  robo_2 = robust_sigma(data[*], GOODVEC=good_indices)
```

Then use (only) those good indices to compute the other moments.

```
  robo_3 = skewness(data[good_indices])
  robo_4 = kurtosis(data[good_indices])
```

No need for a special implementation.